# Generate bar graph or histogram like structure on canvas while playing audio using media player Andorid

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-canvas

I want to show the audio files frequencies to render in histogram like structure and changes the heights of each bar in graph with respect to the audio frequency.

```
Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
      int samplingRate)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
      int samplingRate)
  {

  }
};
```

can any one answer what code has to be write in following methods written above. Thanks in advance.